# Count how often a particular value appears in an array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I know the function `count()` of php,
but what's the function for counting how often a value appear in an array?

Example:

```
$array = array(
  [0] => 'Test',
  [1] => 'Tutorial',
  [2] => 'Video',
  [3] => 'Test',
  [4] => 'Test'
);
```

Now I want to count how often "Test" appears.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PHP has a function called [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) for that.

Example:

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the function `array_count_values` you can find more information about the function in the documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Example from that page:

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Will produce:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Comment: I need something like that, but im using Laravel, so far this:  ```{{ $comment->count(['comment']) }}``` only returns all values within the ```comments``` column. I wish to count the number of comments each post has. In the ```commentable_id``` column is where the id, from a post is stored. As you can imagine, the id duplicates as the post gains more comments.